# SMS GATEWAY USING OZEKING MYSQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ozeki

I'm trying to configure an `SMS GATEWAY` USING `OZEKING` but I'm getting an error which has something to do with `MYSQL ODBC DRIVER` not being found. I have the driver installed on my Windows 10 machine and I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing. In the `OZEKING` configuration I'm seeing this in the picture below:

[image: CONFIG STRING ON OZEKING]

The error I'm getting is :

```
12/16/2015 14:51:47 - INFO 6021: Connecting to database ODBC, DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=dbtest;UID=root;PWD=password@87;.
12/16/2015 14:51:47 - ERROR 6001: Database connection error: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=dbtest;UID=root;PWD=password@87;
12/16/2015 14:51:47 - INFO 6026: Will try to reconnect to database in 20 seconds.
```

My question is what exactly am I doing wrong?
These parameters I'm entering `Server=localhost;Database=dbtest;UID=root;PWD=password@87` are the ones I'm using to connect to my database, i.e:

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "password@87";
$databaseName = "dbtest";

//create connection and select database by given data
$GLOBALS["connection"] = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password);

if ($GLOBALS["connection"] == null)
{
    echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
    return false;
}
```

Anyone to assist me the correct way of doing things. Thanks.

Comment: Please be careful not to post actual passwords on here.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC drivers installed are 32-bit OR 64-bit, make sure you installed the correct architecture for your machine.

(install both to be safe)

Click Start and type "ODBC", you'll be given an option for your 32-bit and 64-bit sources, check them both and make sure your 5.3 driver is installed under both.